# How can I programmatically read the properties inside an MSI file?

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, dtf

Is there a way to read the properties inside an [MSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) file?

For example, given a MSI file named *Testpackage.msi*, I need to find

```
productName
PackageCode
version
```

This I am going to use it with WMI uninstall

```
string objPath = string.Format("Win32_Product.IdentifyingNumber='{0}', Name='{1}', Version='{2}'", "{AC9C1263-2BA8-4863-BE18-01232375CE42}", "testproduct", "10.0.0.0");
```

Using [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557(v=vs.85).aspx) is a great option, if this can be achieved programmatically. Then I can use this to generate automatic release notes. And in un-installing program too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [COM-based API for working with MSI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367810(VS.85).aspx), and do something like

```vb
Function GetVersion(ByVal msiName)

    Const msiOpenDatabaseModeReadOnly = 0
    Dim msi, db, view

    Set msi = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
    Set db = msi.OpenDataBase(msiName, msiOpenDatabaseModeReadOnly)
    Set view = db.OpenView("SELECT `Value` FROM `Property` WHERE `Property` = 'ProductVersion'")
    Call view.Execute()

    GetVersion = view.Fetch().StringData(1)

End Function
```

Comment: Also take a look at the MsiInfo.exe command line tool (also a part of the Windows SDK). It can read and write the summary information of an MSI (Including the Oh-so-painful Package Code)

Comment: Please see my answer below for what I believe is a simpler and more reliable way to access an MSI.

Answer (score 7):

> ***WiX toolset***: [***WiX quick-start tips***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864) (collection of links to resources). WiX installs DTF.

---

I just want to mention that things have gotten even easier now. **There is a full .NET wrapper for the Windows Installer object model, so you can avoid any COM interop clunkiness**.

> ***DTF - Getting Started***: Main file: **`Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll`**
>
> 1. [Download and install the WiX toolkit](https://wixtoolset.org/releases/)
> 2. Find the files below in the **`WixInstallPath\SDK`** directory

The wrapper is called "**Deployment Tools Foundation**" (DTF) and here is the basic description: "*Deployment Tools Foundation is a rich set of .NET class libraries and related resources that together bring the Windows deployment platform technologies into the .NET world. It is designed to greatly simplify deployment-related development tasks while still exposing the complete functionality of the underlying technology*".

**Here is a stripped-down, hands-on sample**:

```cs
using (var db = new Database(FullPath, DatabaseOpenMode.ReadOnly))
{    
  PackageCode = db.SummaryInfo.RevisionNumber;
  AppVendor = db.SummaryInfo.Author;
  AppName = db.SummaryInfo.Title;
  ProductName = db.SummaryInfo.Subject;
  ProductCode = (string)db.ExecuteScalar("SELECT `Value` FROM "+
                 "`Property` WHERE `Property` = 'ProductCode'");
  AppVersion = (string)db.ExecuteScalar("SELECT `Value` FROM "+
                 "`Property` WHERE `Property` = 'ProductVersion'");
  UpgradeCode = (string)db.ExecuteScalar("SELECT `Value` FROM "+
                 " `Property` WHERE `Property` = 'UpgradeCode'");
}
```

**Primary DTF files** (the latter two are the most used ones):

- **Microsoft.Deployment.Compression.dll** - Framework for archive packing and unpacking.
- **Microsoft.Deployment.Compression.Cab.dll** - Implements cabinet archive packing and unpacking.
- **Microsoft.Deployment.Resources.dll** - Classes for reading and writing resource data in executable files.
- **Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll** - Complete .NET based class library for the Windows Installer APIs.
- **Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Package.dll** - Extended classes for working with Windows Installer installation and patch packages.

Just create a C# project, reference these files, and code your own deployment application with whatever control you desire and need. I am not set up with the tools for DTF at the moment, but see [**this sample**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12494760/129130) for a general idea of how a C# program would work.

- DTF is included with WIX. [**Download WiX from here**](http://wixtoolset.org/).
- The DTF dlls are in the SDK folder in the main WiX installation folder (the default location is: %ProgramFiles(x86)%\WiX Toolset v3.10\SDK). The version number will probably be different by the time you see this. Just look for the WiX folder under %ProgramFiles(x86)%.
- Look for the **DTF help files** in the "doc" folder. **DTF.chm** and **DTFAPI.chm**. Absolutely excellent documentation for the object model and its usage.
- See [**this serverfault.com post**](https://serverfault.com/a/596519/20599) for some more DTF details
- [Some starter suggestions for working with WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864)

Comment: The DTF is hidden in WixInstallPath\SDK directory, Microsoft.Deployment.*.dlls.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Microsoft's Orca.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557.aspx).  Orca will allow you to open the MSI and edit/view all the tables in it. You will have to download the entire [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370834(VS.85).aspx) in order to get it, but thankfully that is free.

One alternative (which might be faster due to the download size of the SDK) is to use dark.exe from the [WiX project](http://wix.sourceforge.net/).  Dark is a MSI decompiler, which will export everything into an XML file and collection of resources. The XML it outputs will have the information you are looking for.

Comment: Orca itself is also available from here -> http://astebner.sts.winisp.net/Tools/Orca.zip

Comment: Link seems not anymore valid

Answer (score 3):

Here's a similar example in VBScript which I use as part of my build process in creating bootstrapper executables...

```vb
Option Explicit
Const MY_MSI = "product.msi"

Dim installer, database, view, result, sumInfo, sPackageCode

Set installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
Set database = installer.OpenDatabase (MY_MSI, 0)

Set sumInfo = installer.SummaryInformation(MY_MSI, 0)
sPackageCode =  sumInfo.Property(9) ' PID_REVNUMBER = 9, contains the package code.

WScript.Echo "ProductVersion=" & getproperty("ProductVersion")
WScript.Echo "ProductCode=" & getproperty("ProductCode") 
WScript.Echo "PackageCode=" & sPackageCode 
WScript.Echo "ProductName=" & getproperty("ProductName") 

Function getproperty(property)

    Set view = database.OpenView ("SELECT Value FROM Property WHERE Property='" & property & "'")
    view.Execute
    Set result = view.Fetch
    getproperty = result.StringData(1)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a lightweight non-programmatic solution in [lessmsi](http://code.google.com/p/lessmsi/).   It apparently uses wix and just explodes the whole .msi into a specified folder.  (It also has a UI but it didn't render great for me on Win7).

Comment: What didn't render great? Please let me know on the google code site and I'll investigate. Or, since it is fully open source feel free to submit a patch ;)