# Remove all versions of LogMeIn software

Tags: vbscript, uninstallation, windows-installer

I'm creating a VBScript to remove all found instances of LogMeIn Software. It seems to work installing but it is leaving the registry key. If I run the string manually from the cmd prompt it completely uninstalls, including removing the registry key. What do I need to do to not just execute the MSI uninstall but to also clean up the registry? Thank You

```
On Error Resume Next
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
strComputer = "."
Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" &_
strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
strKeyPath = 
"SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
oReg.EnumKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, arrSubKeys
For Each subkey In arrSubKeys
   strDisplayName = WshShell.RegRead ("HKLM\" & strKeyPath & "\" & subkey 
& "\Contact")
   If  InStr(1, strDisplayName, "LogMeIn") > 0 Then
'   msgbox "C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe /norestart /X " & SubKey & " 
/qn" ' Just for debugging
   WScript.Sleep 20000
   WshShell.Run "cmd /c C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe /X" & SubKey & " 
/qn /L*V msilog.txt", 1, True
   End If
Next
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the string you are "running manually from the cmd prompt".  Whatever that string is, you should be able to simply run that using VBScript: `Set oShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")` 
`oShell.run "cmd.exe your string here"`

Comment: @fkiwergrower Any luck with the RelatedProducts call as described below?

Answer (score 0):

How many instances? Are they using the same upgrade code? You can uninstall all instances by the single upgrade code if so. Here is an example: [Powershell: Uninstall application by UpgradeCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49074826/powershell-uninstall-application-by-upgradecode/49077469#49077469).

> ***UPDATE***: [C# / .NET version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17535555/129130).
>
> There is also the [Windows Installer PowerShell module from Heath Stewart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53436779/129130).

Here is a proposed script inlined - I haven't tested it for reboot scenarios. Just leave the product open and uninstall and see if it triggers a reboot. Invoke via **`cscript.exe`** for silent running:

```
Const msiUILevelNone = 2
Const msiInstallStateAbsent = 2

Set installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
'installer.UILevel = msiUILevelNone ' Disabled to prevent silent uninstall. Now the UAC prompt will show

' Uninstall Orca, replace upgrade code with yours
Set products = installer.RelatedProducts("{UPGRADE-GUID-GOES-HERE-000000000000}")

For Each product In products
   ' MsgBox "Product Code: " & product ' Show the product code found, if you want

   ' The following call when run silently with admin rights may reboot the system without warning!
   ' This is due to badly authored MSI packages - most packages will not trigger this problem.
   installer.ConfigureProduct product, 0,  msiInstallStateAbsent ' Uninstall product

   ' See text above for info on the newer ConfigureProductEx method.
Next

Set installer = Nothing

MsgBox "Finished" ' Just so we know the script ran if nothing found to uninstall
```