# Store msi path when it’s copied to windows installer

Tags: c#, windows-installer, installation

I’m currently developing a C# project that has a Setup Installer project. During the installation process, is there any way to access the path (especially the name) of the copied MSI file (it gets cached in C:\Windows\Installer) ?

I would like to store this somewhere in a text file in order to be able to uninstall my application directly from within a Form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***Uninstall***: There is no need to access that file directly, there are plenty of ways to uninstall without using the cached file name:
>   [Uninstalling an MSI file from the command line without using msiexec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec/1055933#1055933).
>
> The easiest is just to uninstall [by product code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937568/how-can-i-find-the-product-guid-of-an-installed-msi-setup/29937569#29937569):
>
> ```
> msiexec.exe /x {PRODUCT-CODE-1111-1111-11111111111X}
> ```

And you can uninstall [by upgrade code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58310840/129130) ([2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102058/is-msiopenproduct-the-correct-way-to-read-properties-from-an-installed-product/48615123#48615123)), or [by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48669243/is-there-an-alternative-to-guid-when-using-msiexec-to-uninstall-an-application/48670801#48670801):

- [WIX (remove all previous versions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51404270/wix-remove-all-previous-versions/51412022#51412022)

---

You are not trying to uninstall the application that is running from its own GUI are you? :-) Breaking the law. Breaking the law. Wouldn't try that.

---

***LocalPath***: There are also several ways to retrieve that local cache path via the MSI API:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")

' The product name you search for:
search = "Windows SDK EULA"

For Each product In installer.ProductsEx("", "", 7)
   name = product.InstallProperty("ProductName")
   cachepath=product.InstallProperty("LocalPackage")
   If name = search Then
      MsgBox name + ": " + cachepath
      Exit For
   End If
Next
```

[image: Local Cache Path]

---

***Links***:

- [Technical Tidbit: Finding Related Product Codes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47856560/129130)

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! The last part did the trick perfectly ! Just a question, why do you say that it would be braking the law to uninstall from within the application itself ? Unfortunately I need to do that as it is requested for a client, even though I find it really dangerous and awkward too !

Comment: That was just a joke. Then you have to shut down quickly to make that work OK, any open documents that need to be saved? Maybe it is just a viewer? It is very non-standard :-). Wouldn't recommend it, people should uninstall from the Add/Remove applet. I just wrote [an answer showing how to launch that applet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58822061/129130).

Comment: 'msiexec.exe /x {C760BC0B-D320-4DBB-997F-EF535DA0E963}' gives me error "This action is only valid for products that are currently installed.", even though I can't install the same version, so apparently there are some leftovers or registry keys that prevent installing.