# Wix Installer app won't install when run twice and uninstalls the app

Tags: c#, wix, wix3.5, wix3, wix3.7

I wrote a simple wix installer with gui, which installs well. But when I run the same .msi file  a second time, it takes me through the normal installation process in the gui, but uninstalls my app at the end. 
Then if I run this same .msi file a third time, the installer still does through the installation gui normally, but ends up doing "uninstallation".

I don't understand why it doesn't behave like every other installer and handle installation and uninstallation gracefully.

here is part of my product xml

```
 <Product Id="*" Language="1033" Codepage="1252" Name="..." 
       Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Manufacturer="..." UpgradeCode="BDF9E310-5897-48D4-AB08-889D405F9X56">

<Package InstallerVersion="300" Platform="x64" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Manufacturer="..." 
         Comments="..." Description="..." Keywords="..."/>

<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
```

Comment: What is value of `var.ProductVersion`? Also have you tried to check the msi log files? I guess, that removal is happens because msi detects a previous installation is old one

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski The version is in defined in the project file. And this issue happens when I run the same version of the installer twice.

Comment: MSI recognizes only first 3 digits in version, forth is omitted. If you want run the same version again and again, try to set `AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes"` inside `MajorUpgrade`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski yeah, thanks, I did that, but it causes an error and my installer bugs. when I check the log files I find that this error message is thrown repetitively : "Disallowing uninstallation of component: {8150336E-3...AC20CE771A88} "

Comment: Can you share the complete wix code and error from log file? Usually this error happens when MSI package is broken

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski The log file is 6MB large, because the installer recursively logs these message:   "PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MIGRATE property. Its value is '{58AD8C9B-D71E-4762-B25C-C231CCAE7C40}'."   and    "Disallowing uninstallation of component: {504EB49B-F2F0-58FD-AE06-66972EC9AF39} since another client exists"

Answer (score 2):

```
<Product Id="*" Name="..."  Version="" Manufacturer="..." UpgradeCode="...">
```

> ***Auto-GUID***: The **`Id="*"`** section means "auto generate product code" (the use of the **`*`** means auto-generate). When you do that
>   every build or rebuild of your setup gets a new product code. This
>   amounts to a major upgrade in MSI-terms if you also change the
>   **`ProductVersion`** (in one of the first 3 digits) AND you have a **`MajorUpgrade element`** such as the one you are using in the source (which is standard by the way).
>
> ***Solution***: You can hard code a product code if you like to be able to control when it changes.

---

> ***Note***: You might be in a dirty state on the system with many "overlapping" installations. Look for duplicate installations of your product by opening the Add / Remove Programs applet: <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + Tap <kbd>R</kbd> => **`appwiz.cpl`** => <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I would uninstall all instances, and maybe prefer to test setups on virtuals henceforth? (this also helps to discover hidden runtime depenencies - provided the virtual is saved without most runtimes).

---

***Links***: Some links with some background information on major upgrades.

***MSI SDK***:

- **https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/major-upgrades**

***Flexera / Installshield***:

- [**Major Upgrade vs. Minor Upgrade vs. Small Update**](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield22helplib/helplibrary/MajorMinorSmall.htm)
- [About component, package, product and upgrade codes in Windows Installer](https://media.flexera.com/documents/0012_50ef.pdf)
- [Creating MSI Update Packages](https://media.flexera.com/documents/IS_Tip_Creating-MSI-Update-Packages.pdf)
- [Designing an Update-Friendly MSI Installation](https://media.flexera.com/documents/IS_Tip_Designing-Update-Friendly-MSI-Installation.pdf)
- https://www.flexerasoftware.com/install/products/installshield/installshield-tips-tricks.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've gone through the links you shared, and they contain valuable information, but I couldn't find my solution.

Comment: But A temporary work arround was to change my upgrade code for evey new version of the installer.