# DTF is included with new WIX releases - looking for an example of this for VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix, dtf

[How to programmatically read the properties inside an MSI file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298841/msi-file-reading/1061606#1061606)

Looking for VS2010 example I can test and learn with.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example DTF Managed Custom Action to list the available websites on IIS:

http://blog.torresdal.net/2008/10/24/WiXAndDTFUsingACustomActionToListAvailableWebSitesOnIIS.aspx