# How to use ISPP to split a file size into lo / hi bits for the DwinsHs_Check function

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript, dwinshs

Take this script:

```
Source: "{tmp}\HelpDocSetup.exe"; \
    DestDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: external deleteafterinstall; \
    Tasks: downloadhelp; \
    Check: DwinsHs_Check( ExpandConstant('{tmp}\HelpDocSetup.exe'), '{#HelpDocSetupURL}', 'My_Setup', 'Get', 0, 0 )
```

See the `0, 0` at the end of the line?

---

According to the documentation for [`DwinsHs_Check`](https://www.han-soft.com/releases/dwinshs/documents/f_check.html) it states:

> - **FileSize : LongInt**
>
>   Together with the `FileSizeHigh` parameter specifies
>     the file size in bytes. It will be used to calculate the download
>     progress and remaining time. This avoids delays before the download
>     begins because the script doesn't have to fetch the file size from
>     the server.
>
>   This parameter specifies the **low 31 bits** of the file size, and the `FileSizeHigh` parameter specifies the **high 31 bits** of the file size. Note, not 32 bits.
>
>   Note, the file size will be fetched from the server if the parameter
>     is set to `FILESIZE_QUERY_SERVER (0)`, `FILESIZE_UNKNOWN (-1)`, or
>     `FILESIZE_KEEP_FORMER (-2)`. In this case, the value of `FileSize`
>     parameter will be ignored.
>
>   Note, only digital value can be used in this parameter, the constant
>     identifier cannot be used.
> - **FileSizeHigh: LongInt**
>
>   Together with the `FileSize` parameter specifies
>     the file size in bytes. It will be used to calculate the download
>     progress and remaining time. This avoids delays before the download
>     begins because the script doesn't have to fetch the file size from
>     the server.
>
>   This parameter specifies the **high 31 bits** of the
>     file size, and the `FileSize` parameter specifies the **low 31 bits** of
>     the file size.
>
>   Note, the value of this parameter will be ignored if the FileSize
>     parameter is set to `FILESIZE_QUERY_SERVER (0)`, `FILESIZE_UNKNOWN (-1)`,
>     or `FILESIZE_KEEP_FORMER (-2)`.
>
>   Note, only digital value can be used in this parameter, the constant
>     identifier cannot be used.

---

This particular setup file is also on my computer. Relative to the main ISS file the path would be:

> `..\HelpNDoc\CHM\Output\PublicTalksHelpDocumentationSetup.exe`

Can we use ISPP to extract the file size and split it as the two parameters required for `DwinsHs_Check`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`FileSize` preprocessor function](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=filesize) to retrieve the file size. But it's limited to 2GB = 31 bits. What corresponds to the `FileSize` argument of `DwinsHs_Check`:

```
#define ExeSize FileSize("..\HelpNDoc\CHM\Output\PublicTalksHelpDocumentationSetup.exe")

Check: DwinsHs_Check( ExpandConstant('{tmp}\HelpDocSetup.exe'), '{#HelpDocSetupURL}', \
       'My_Setup', 'Get', {#ExeSize}, 0)
```

---

If the file could theoretically be over 2GB, you would have to use other means to retrieve the file size – e.g. by calling PowerShell code with [`Exec` preprocessor function](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=exec). And you should split the size into the two parts in the PowerShell (or other) code straight away, as the Inno Setup preprocessor cannot work with 64-bit numbers anyway.

For examples of calling PowerShell code and returning its results, see:

- [How to get file version of msi file in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48550432/850848)
- [Retrieve strong name of .NET assembly in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45996803/850848)
- [Disassembling strings from Inno Setup [Code]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49194957/850848)