# How to open MSI table in Delphi?

Tags: windows, delphi, windows-installer

I need to open some tables from MSI database, read this and place some rows in this with using Delphi (in my example is Delphi 7 but allowed other versions if it needed).

For example it would look like ORCA. Msi must be open, written to the table where it's can be edited and written to the msi file.

By default, Delphi can't open MSI tables as I thing but I found a [JEDI Windows API](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JEDI_Windows_API_Library) where exists libraris like JwaMsi and JwaMsiQuery. But I can't find documentations or examples of using functions like

```
function MsiOpenProduct(szProduct: LPCTSTR; var hProduct: MSIHANDLE): UINT; stdcall;
{$EXTERNALSYM MsiOpenProduct}
```

By the way, while I search information about this I found this code:

```
const msilib = 'msi.dll';

type

  MSIHANDLE = DWORD;    
  TMsiHandle = MSIHANDLE;

function MsiCloseHandle(hAny: MSIHANDLE):UINT;stdcall;external msilib name 'MsiCloseHandle';
function MsiOpenProduct(szProduct:LPCSTR;var hProduct:MSIHANDLE):UINT;stdcall;external msilib name 'MsiOpenProductA';
function MsiGetProductProperty(hProduct:MSIHANDLE;szProperty:LPCSTR;lpValueBuf:LPSTR;pcchValueBuf:LPDWORD):UINT;stdcall; external msilib name 'MsiGetProductPropertyA';
function MsiSetInternalUI(dwUILevel:INSTALLUILEVEL;phWnd:LPHWND):INSTALLUILEVEL;stdcall;     external msilib name 'MsiSetInternalUI';

function GetMSIProperty(aProductCode:string):string;
var
 msi:TMSIHandle;
 t:string;

 function _getmsiproperty(_name:string):string;
 var
  txt:PChar;
  sz:DWORD;
 begin
  sz:=MAX_PATH;
  txt:=AllocMem(sz+1);
  if MsiGetProductProperty(msi,PChar(_name),txt,@sz)=ERROR_MORE_DATA then
   begin
    ReAllocMem(txt,sz+1);
    MsiGetProductProperty(msi,PChar(_name),txt,@sz);
   end;
  SetString(Result,txt,sz);
  FreeMem(txt,sz+1);
 end;

begin
 MsiSetInternalUI(2,nil); // скрываем GUI/hide GUI
 if MsiOpenProduct(PChar(aProductCode),msi)=ERROR_SUCCESS then
  begin
   t:=_getmsiproperty('ARPPRODUCTICON'); // главная иконка приложения/main program icon
       if t='' then t:=_getmsiproperty('ProductIcon');
       if t='' then t:=_getmsiproperty('CompleteSetupIcon');
       if t='' then t:=_getmsiproperty('CustomSetupIcon');
       if t='' then t:=_getmsiproperty('InfoIcon');
       if t='' then t:=_getmsiproperty('InstallerIcon');
       if t='' then t:=_getmsiproperty('RemoveIcon');
       if t='' then t:=_getmsiproperty('RepairIcon');
       Result:=t;
       MsiCloseHandle(msi);
  end;
end;
```

What is better to use and where I can see documentation and/or examples?

P.S. Sorry for my English

Comment: Documentation is on MSDN. For example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa370341(v=vs.85).aspx The best examples are likely to be written in C++. Websearch will take you to them.

Comment: Thank you! I have read this page and I think that better way is use [MsiOpenPackageEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370340(v=vs.85).aspx) because will be open msi that not installed yet. Sorry but now I have new questions: I need to use something like `MsiOpenPackageEx(%path_to_msi%, 1, %variable_name%)` ? What is variable type is needed?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I think you need to find some good C++ examples and work from there. Good luck! I know this isn't the easiest library to work with!

Comment: Thank you again! If I can do that I want it will be shared here with other.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the  COM-based API to MSI.

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298841/msi-file-reading) and the [MSI API documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367810%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: That would be my vote also.  Delphi is very COM centric so it would make sense to go throughthe WindowsInstaller.Installer automation interface rather then the Win32 API functions.

Comment: Is the automation interface (and it is automation rather than plain COM) really easier to use?

Answer (score 0):

So, solution exist and I do it! It's not so gracefully but it's working...

At first, read articles from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368250%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (in my case is articles about work with MSI database).
At second, you must understand what you need to do. In my case it is:

1. Open msi database
2. Read table names
3. Read needed table and show it
4. If it needed - make changes and save it

Here I show how I do the three first steps.

Preparing

---

Download [JEDI Windows AP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/files/) (for easer work with msi) and add to project JwaMsi.pas, JwaMsiDefs.pas and JwaMsiQuery.pas (do not forget about USES list). Dependencies will be added automatically.
Next, place on form all needed components.

Let's code!

1 Open msi database and 2 Read table names

---

Define variables for handlers and for buffers

```
var msi_handler_DB, msi_handler_view, msi_handler_record:TMSIHandle;
txt:PChar;
sz:DWORD;
```

Now we need take a list of tables ([more info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368259%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and place it in ListBox, for example

```
begin
  sz:=MAX_PATH;           //initialise
  txt:=AllocMem(sz+1);    //variables
OpenDialog1.Execute;      //select file
If MsiOpenDatabase(PChar(OpenDialog1.FileName), MSIDBOPEN_DIRECT, msi_handler_DB)=ERROR_SUCCESS //check if DB is open
  then begin                                                                                    //start reading
  Listbox1.Clear;   //prepare listbox for filling
  MsiDatabaseOpenView(msi_handler_DB, 'SELECT * FROM _Tables',msi_handler_view);  //prepare query to _Table
  MsiViewExecute(msi_handler_view, msi_handler_record);                           //execute...
  While not MsiViewFetch(msi_handler_view, msi_handler_record)=ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS   //and fetch it in cycle until end of table
    do begin
      MsiRecordGetString(msi_handler_record,1,txt,sz);    //read string
      ListBox1.Items.Add(txt);                            //and write to listbox
    end;                                                                          //end of fetch cycle

  MsiCloseAllHandles;                                     //close handles (we don't need they more)
  end;                                                                                          //stop reading
end;
```

3 Read needed table and show it

---

It's easy!

```
 begin
 edit1.text:=Listbox1.Items.ValueFromIndex[ListBox1.ItemIndex];
If MsiOpenDatabase(PChar(OpenDialog1.FileName), MSIDBOPEN_DIRECT, msi_handler_DB)=ERROR_SUCCESS //open database again
  then begin
  MsiDatabaseExport(msi_handler_DB, pchar(ListBox1.Items.Strings[ListBox1.ItemIndex]), 'C:\Windows\Temp', Pchar(ListBox1.Items.Strings[ListBox1.ItemIndex]+'.idt')); //export table to .idt
  MsiCloseAllHandles; //and close handler again

//...
//here must be placed code for
//parsing .idt as tabulation separated file
//with wordwrap and show it.
//for example - in StringGrid
//...

DeleteFile('C:\Windows\Temp\'+ ListBox1.Items.Strings[ListBox1.ItemIndex]+'.idt');  //do not forget delete temporary .idt file. save our planet! :)
  end;
end;
```

4 If it needed - make changes and save it

---

Just repeat third step from the end to beginning: export StringGrid to file (about .idt and it's structure you can read here: [one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372075%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [two](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [three](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), import in to MSI with property MsiDatabaseImport (do not forget open database before and append it after, also remember about close handlers) and delete temporary .idt file.

Good luck!

P.S. Sorry for my English, part two :)

Comment: Additional info: some tables, like "_Tables" or "CCP" is a hidden system tables and can not be exported. I see two ways: query to that tables or just ignore (and hide from list of tables) it.