# What are the differences between COM msi.dll WindowsInstaller and Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller?

Tags: installation, windows-installer

What are the differences between COM msi.dll WindowsInstaller and Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller?

I know one exists in %WINDIR%\system32\msi.dll and the other exists in Visual Studio's reference assemblies list.

I know the implementation of the Installer objects are completely different.

Why are there two different implementation of WindowsInstaller? and why are they called the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***MSI API***: The Windows Installer API is quite old and is implemented as **`Win32 C/C++ functions`** and a layer of **`COM automation`** on top (which you can use VBScript and many other languages to access). This is all implemented in the ***`%WINDIR%\system32\msi.dll`*** file (and whatever other support files are involved - I am not quite sure - there is also *`msiexec.exe`* of course - the actual installation engine and command line tool to install and configure MSI packages and *`msihnd.dll`* - and a few more I think).

***DTF*** *(Deployment Tools Foundation)*: As the .NET framework and managed code came of age, the use of COM and Win32 functions was kind of clunky and the Deployment Tools Foundation kit - also known as *`DTF was implemented to help use the MSI API with managed code`*. The file: **`Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll`** is one of the files delivered as part of DTF and the most commonly used one. The WiX toolkit now installs DTF as part of its normal installation. **Please check the links below**.

***Links***:

- [**A sample of DTF code and more details**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1061606/129130) (recommended - [see same page for COM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/328710/129130)).
- [The various APIs for MSI files](https://serverfault.com/a/596519/20599).

---

Note, there are also some **WMI** functions.

Comment: Stein, thank you so much for the answer again. I did little bit more digging about DTF and saw the help file which was very helpful. However, I am encountering an issue on both of them for specific GUID using C#. Would you mind taking a look at my code? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63159991/why-is-vbs-able-to-find-the-installlocation-when-c-sharp-using-both-dtf-and-msi